# How to stop ComboBox SelectionChange from SelectionChanged Event

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ComboBox which is binded with a List. Consider I have 10 Items in the List, so in the combobox also.

Currently 2nd Item is selected in the ComboBox.

Now I am selecting the 3rd item in the ComboBox.

In the Combobox SelectionChanged event, I am doing some validation and validation fails so I don want my Selection is changed from 2nd item to 3rd item or the selection should remain in 2nd item.

Please let me know how to do this?

In the ComboBox SelectionChanged event, I tried to set ComboBox.SelectedItem = 2ndItem.

But this didn't work properly.

Hope, my requirement is clear. If you have any doubt then please feel free to ask me.

regards,

Vimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the item so that the user sees that they are currently not an option (and also can not select). You can set the IsEnabled-property on the ComboBoxItem.

If you work with MVVM, add an IsEnabled-property to your ViewModel and bind it on the IsEnabled-property of the container (`ItemContainerStyle`).

The best option IMO would however be, not to show the items that are not selectable.

**Update**

As promised in a comment, here the Dispatcher-Code to set the SelectedItem delayed:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {  
    yourComboBox.SelectedItem=yourOldItem;       
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

I think this will help, however it's not very nice. If you have the possibility to disable or hide the items, this would be much better. BTW, I took ContextIdle for the dispatcher-priority. This is a very strong value. You can play around which value fits to your needs.

**CoerceValueCallback**

Another possibility would be to derive from `Combobox`, change the metadata for the SelectedItem and add a `CoerceValueCallback` to it. There in, you can reset the value.

Comment: Sorry, I cant Disable the Item. The validation fails only based on the validation logic inside the SelectionChanged event

Comment: @ksvimal: You can try to select back with the Dispatcher. It will then be selected back after all UI-Work has been done. This will help, however is IMO a dirty hack. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi, It works. Thanks for your feedback :-) Can I have your private mail id?

Comment: Hi, I have another problem regarding this issue. your code works fine but the problem is user can see that selection is coming to the 3rd row and again going to the 2nd row. I don want the selection to change. that is if the validation fails i want to stop the SelectionChange itself. Hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: Try the CoerceValueCallback-version. It is a little bit more complicated, but propbably will do what you want. Another, maybe more simple solution, is to create an AttachedProperty named ValidatedSelectedItem and in the DependencyPropertyChanged-event you sync the SelectedItem of the ComboBox. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx. For this solution you also can use the CoerceValueCallback to reset the value but you can do it also directly in the changed-handler. Hope this helped.

Comment: @HCL the link in your comment is now dead